# Unlock by fingerprint only

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, security, 7.0-nougat, pattern-lock, fingerprint

When I initially set up my phone, I had to both choose a pattern and scan my fingerprint, for providing maximal security.
Now, when I want to unlock my phone, I can choose, whether I want to do that with the pattern or with my fingerprint.

Why providing the fingerprint, when someone still can use my pattern?
Is there any way, to deactivate the pattern, so that it can be unlocked by the **fingerprint only**?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible since FP is less secure than password/pattern. And there's another reason.

FP is stored as a "credential", which is by default, encrypted. That's why whenever you reboot your phone, or haven't unlocked your phone for 24 hours, you must unlock with pattern before you can use FP again.

Comment: That doesn't entirely make sense, seems just arbitrary. Why can't they just store the FB the way of the PIN? It juts forces someone to give two ways of people to break in their phone!

Comment: @Itai Only because you need to unlock the key to decrypt your `/data`. While a PIN or pattern can provide a numeric passcode for a key, a FP can't. That's why FP is never used for encryption, but only for identity verification.

Comment: You'd imagine the FP is stored as a series of binary digits somewhere, but maybe I'm thinking too digital ;)

Comment: @Itai It's not what *I think*, it's what Android actually *is doing*.